# number of roots between $1<|z|<2$

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

let $f(z)=z^9+z^5+8z^3+2z+1$, well, $$|f(z)-z^9|=|z^5+8z^3+2z+1|<|2|^9\text{ at } |z|=2$$ so $f$ has $9$ zeroes inside $|z|<2$

and $$|f(z)-8z^3|=|z^9+z^5+2z+1|<5<8|z|^3\text{ at } |z|=1$$ so inside $|z|<1$ $f$ has 3 zeroes, so $6$ zeroes are there inside $1<z<2$, could any one tell me whether I have properly applied [Rouché’s theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) to this problem? Thank you for reply.

Comment: ah! I am sorry I could not properly hyperlinked the page

Comment: Fixed it. URIs involving accents and stuff often don't work the way they should.

Comment: You are correct and have supplied a complete proof. Source: I just finished a course in Complex Analysis at my university.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSE community hereby certifies the proof as correct and complete. (Maybe add a word about no roots on boundary circles).